# holomorphic complex function such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=n\space$ but $f$ is not identically $1/z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Find a function $f(z)$ holomorphic on $\{0<|z|<1\}$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=n\space$  for each integer $n >1 $, but so that $f$ is not identically $1/z$.

I attempted to solve this and I found that by the uniquness theorem, such a function cannot have a pole in $z=0$, hence this function must have an essential singularity on $z=0$. Although I couldn't proceed from here...

Any hint would help, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $f(z) = (1/z)e^{2\pi i/ z}$ is holomorphic on $\{0 < |z| < 1\}$ and satisfies $f(\frac{1}{n}) = ne^{2\pi i n} = n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Moreover, $f(z)$ is not identically $1/z$.

Comment: Get, thanks! don't know how it didn't occur to me :)

Answer (score 4):

Multiply $z\mapsto 1/z$ by a holomorphic function $g$ on $\{0<|z|<1\}$ such that $g(1/n)=1$ for each $n$. For example, $g(z)=\cos( 2\pi /z)$.

Comment: Great, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right)$$

That means add any holomorphic function $g$ from $\{0<|z|<1\}$ to itself with $f$ such that $g(\frac{1}{n})=0$.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks!